# Does TFS / TFVC not like dotfiles?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I'm trying to add some files in TFS 2015 that begin with a period.

```
.babelrc
.eslintrc.js
.eslintignore
```

In Visual Studio 2015, when I select "Add Items to Folder..." these files don't show up in the list.

It seems that Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) doesn't consider these valid file names. Or it "helpfully" assumes that I will never want to add them to source control. I haven't been able to find documentation that clarifies one way or another.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: you can always use git cli to add them to repo

Comment: @EdwardThomson TFVC. Got my acronyms mixed up. I've updated the question.